# Rewrite rule and the_request

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, request-uri

How to rewrite `search/2` from `index.php?search="x"&&searc_by="y"&page_no=2`?

If I am not wrong `%REQUEST_URI` is `search/2`, right? Also what is `%THE_REQUEST` in this case.

The page where `search/2` link is located is rewritten as just home_page.

Comment: - RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-fRewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Home_Page/([A-Za-z-0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$  -RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ kl.php?$1&page_no=$2 [L,NC]

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Home_Page/([A-Za-z-0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$  RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ kl.php?$1&page_no=$2 [L,NC]

Comment: Please use the edit button under your post to edit that information in. As you can see, it is not readable in the comments. Please use the buttons above the edit field to format this as code. Please pay a little attention to spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_URI}` and `%{THE_REQUEST}` are variables in mod_rewrite. These variables contain the following:

- `%{REQUEST_URI}` will contain everything behind the hostname and before the query string. In the url `http://www.example.com/its/a/scary/polarbear?truth=false`, `%{REQUEST_URI}` would contain `/its/a/scary/polarbear`. This variable updates after every rewrite.
- `%{THE_REQUEST}` is a variable that contains the entire request as it was made to the server. This is something in the form of `GET /its/a/scary/polarbear?truth=false HTTP/1.1`. Since the request that was made to the server is static in the lifespan of one such request, this variable does not change when a rewrite is made. It is therefore helpful in certain situations where you only want to rewrite if an external request contained something. It is often used to prevent infinite loops from happening.

A complete list of variables can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

---

In your case you will have a link to `search/2?search=x&search_by=y`. You want to internally rewrite this to `index.php?search=x&search_by=y&page_no=2`. You can do this with the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?page_no=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The first argument matches the external request that comes in. It is then rewritten to `/index.php?page_no=2`. The `QSA` (query string append) flag appends the existing query string to the rewritten query string. You end up with `/index.php?search=x&search_by=y&page_no=2`. The `L` flag stops this 'round' of rewriting. It's just an optimalization thing.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question, when I do RewriteRule ^search/([0-9]+)$ does it also try to match the query that i appended whil creating the link: search/2?search=x&search_by=y.

Comment: Everything behind the `?` is the query string. The query string is not matched in the first argument of `RewriteRule`. Since I use the QSA-flag, the original query string 'falls through' and is available in the rewritten url just as it was available in the original url.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search/                
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-]+)/? $ kl.php?$1 [L,NC,QSA]                                  My internal link is: /search?($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Comment: I have no clue what a CGI error is. As far as I know it is unrelated to mod_rewrite, as that would cause an internal server error and an entry in apache's error log.